# XML to CSV issues

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file which contains citations from a literature search. I am trying to parse this into a CSV to open with excel, only importing some of the nodes. The XML file has several thousand entries. One such entry is:

```
<records>
<rec resultID="1">
    <controlInfo>
      <bkinfo>
        <btl>Effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer.</btl>
      </bkinfo>
      <dissinfo />
      <jinfo>
        <jtl>European Journal of Oncology Nursing</jtl>
        <issn>14623889</issn>
      </jinfo>
      <pubinfo>
        <dt year="2017" month="12" day="01">Dec2017</dt>
        <vid>31</vid>
      </pubinfo>
      <artinfo>
        <ui type="doi">10.1016/j.ejon.2017.08.005</ui>
        <ppf>46</ppf>
        <ppct>6</ppct>
        <formats />
        <tig>
          <atl>Effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer.</atl>
        </tig>
        <aug>
          <au>Chimluang, Janya</au>
          <au>Thanasilp, Sureeporn</au>
          <affil>Faculty of Nursing, Chulalongkorn University, Bangkok, Thailand</affil>
        </aug>
        <ab>Purpose To evaluate the effect of an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles on the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. Methods This quasi-experimental research study had pre- and post-test control groups. The experimental group received conventional care and an intervention based on basic Buddhist principles for three consecutive days, including seven activities based on precept activities, concentration activities and wisdom activities. The control group received conventional care alone. Results Forty-eight patients participated in this study: 23 in the experimental group and 25 in the control group. Their mean age was 53 (standard deviation 10) years. The spiritual well-being of participants in the experimental group was significantly higher than that of participants in the control group at the second post-test ( P &lt; 0.05). Conclusions An intervention based on basic Buddhist principles improved the spiritual well-being of patients with terminal cancer. This result supports the beneficial effects of implementing this type of intervention for patients with terminal cancer.</ab>
        <pubtype>Academic Journal</pubtype>
        <doctype>research</doctype>
        <doctype>Article</doctype>
      </artinfo>
      <language>English</language>
    </controlInfo>
    <displayInfo>
      <pLink>
        <url>http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=jlh&amp;AN=126392076&amp;site=ehost-live</url>
      </pLink>
    </displayInfo>
</rec>
</records>
```

What I want to do is import:

- the first au (author)
- jtl (journal title)
- dt (date)
- vid (volume number)
- ppf (first page)
- ppct (page count)
- btl (article title)
- ab (abstract)

I am trying the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("citations.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

citation_data = open('test.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(citation_data)

count = 0

head = ['Author','Title']
csvwriter.writerow(head)

for member in root.findall('records'):
    citation = []
    au = member.find('rec').find('controlInfo').find('artinfo').find('aug').find('au').text
    citation.append(au)
    btl = member.find('rec').find('controlInfo').find('bkinfo').find('btl').text
    citation.append(btl)
    csvwriter.writerow(citation)
citation_data.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    au = member.find('controlInfo').find('artinfo').find('aug').find('au').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I have tried several variants on this code, including not having the recurring ".find", but I get the same thing.

I can't find a solution in any of the other examples here. I am hoping for some gentle guidance and help as i am new to python and this is my first project.

Thanks

A

Comment: The best solution for this job would be using XSLT. There [are many XML to CSV solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+XML+to+CSV) here on SO.

Comment: Your code and example works for me (after I put the record inside a top node).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Why do I need to add another top node? In any case, even when I do that I get only output of the header rows into the csv, not the data. I will have a look at xslt also.

Answer (score 0):

some entry `<record>` in the xml is missing this structure

```
<artinfo>
  <aug>
```

so `member.find('controlInfo').find('artinfo').find('aug').find('au')` couldn't find one of the tags and return `None` so you missing `<aug>` or `<artinfo>`

check after each find is the return value is not None in order to call the next find, smth like

```
a = member.find('controlInfo')
if a is not None: 
  a = a.find('artinfo') 

and so on...
```